# Automatically repeat running a piece of code 25 times and collate the output

Tags: r

I have some code which essentially takes a column of data (`df$Discharge`) and then randomly removes 10% of it and then calculates the 10th percentile on remaining data. I would like to automatically repeat this process 25 times and collate the results into some form of output.

Any help is much appreciated and I could not see any link to other questions that seemed to help directly. Apologies if I have overlooked something.

```
#random removal of 10% of the data
ten_perc_rem <-flow.df %>% sample_frac(0.90)

#calculation of 10th percentile on remainder of data
quantile(ten_perc_rem$Discharge, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You can use the `replicate` function. Just `replicate(25, { ... your  code ... })`. However, it is very likely that you are doing a randomization test or machine learning, in which case there are better tools for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a part of the code and basically need the following missing steps:

**1. Save results**

You can simply save the results as a data frame like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(quantile(ten_perc_rem$Discharge, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**2. Collate results**

For any subsequent "round" you can add the results to the existing data frame like this:

```r
df <- rbind(df,data.frame(quantile(ten_perc_rem$Discharge, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

**3. Loop 25 times**

So let's say you have your script ready to get the results and save/add them in a data frame. How to repeat 25 times?

```r
sum <- 0
results <- data.frame() # empty data frame to store the results

repeat{

repeat_quantile(df,results) # df is your data frame, results is the output data frame

sum = sum+1
 print(sum)
 if (sum == 25){
 print("repeat loop ends");
 break
 }
}
```

This will repeat the function `repeat_quantile` 25 times. Now we just have to define the function to do exactly what you want it to do

```r
repeat_quantile <- function(df,results){

   ten_perc_rem <- df %>% sample_frac(0.90)

   results <- rbind(results,data.frame(quantile(ten_perc_rem$Discharge, probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
```

Comment: you should have a look to `lapply`, `reduce` and other similar functions that will make your life easier when using R

Comment: @denis I really have to familiarize myself with `purr`but to be honest I avoid loops and repeating whenever I can, so I did not have to use it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give example data when asking a question. Let's consider:

```
flow.df <- data.frame(Discharge = runif(100))
```

You can use `sapply`, which is a loop from the `lapply` family trying to give easy output:

```
result <- sapply(1:25,function(i){
  flow.df %>% 
    sample_frac(0.90) %>% 
    select(Discharge) %>%
    quantile( probs = 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)
})
```

It gives you a vector of the quantiles:

```
> result
      90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90% 
0.9538099 0.8988839 0.9290692 0.9290692 0.9290692 0.9295052 0.9538099 0.9538099 0.9538099 
      90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90% 
0.9538099 0.9538099 0.9290692 0.9538099 0.9110256 0.9295052 0.9538099 0.9290692 0.9538099 
      90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90%       90% 
0.9290692 0.9290692 0.9538099 0.9290692 0.9110256 0.9290692 0.9110256
```

If you more into `dplyr`, you should have a look to all the `purr` functions family